# Only 25 entries are stored in JSON files while scraping data using Scrapy; how to increase?

Tags: python, json, scrapy

I am scraping data using Scrapy in a `item.json` file. Data is getting stored but the problem is only 25 entries are stored, while in the website there are more entries. I am using the following command:

```
class DmozSpider(Spider):
name = "dmoz"
allowed_domains = ["justdial.com"]
start_urls = ["http://www.justdial.com/Delhi-NCR/Taxi-Services/ct-57371"]
def parse(self, response):
    hxs = Selector(response)
    sites = hxs.xpath('//section[@class="rslwrp"]/section')
    items = []
    for site in sites:
        item = DmozItem()
        item['title'] = site.xpath('section[2]/section[1]/aside[1]/p[1]/span/a/text()').extract()
        items.append(item)
    return items
```

The command I'm using to run the script is:

```
scrapy crawl myspider -o items.json -t json
```

Is there any setting which I am not aware of? or the page is not getting loaded fully till scraping. how do i resolve this?

Comment: please append the start-url here, and the thing is it must be your code not the command which yields only 25 entries. Most probably for the pagination they are using some ajax request or something. Please post the spider code too

Comment: @Jithin i have updated my post, plz have a look

Comment: @Abhi you just get first 25 results from the site as I see. To get all the results you should also find out how to create pagination request and return it as well. Btw, it is better to use yield in Scrapy spiders instead of collecting data into a list.

Comment: @artemdevel thanks for your quick response. as i am new to Scrapy n all, can you please elaborate with example?

Answer (score 0):

Abhi, here is some code, but please note that it isn't complete and working, it is just to show you the idea. Usually you have to find a next page URL and try to recreate the appropriate request in your spider. In your case AJAX is used. I used FireBug to check which requests are sent by the site.

```
URL = "http://www.justdial.com/function/ajxsearch.php?national_search=0&...page=%s" # this isn't the complete next page URL
next_page = 2 # how to handle next_page counter is up to you

def parse(self, response):
    hxs = Selector(response)
    sites = hxs.xpath('//section[@class="rslwrp"]/section')
    for site in sites:
        item = DmozItem()
        item['title'] = site.xpath('section[2]/section[1]/aside[1]/p[1]/span/a/text()').extract()
        yield item

    # build you pagination URL and send a request
    url = self.URL % self.next_page
    yield Request(url) # Request is Scrapy request object here
    # increment next_page counter if required, make additional 
    # checks and actions etc
```

Hope this will help.